# Как настроить IlSpy для показа "реального" кода?

Tags: c#, .net

В статьях часто пишут, что "такой-то код компилятор разворачивает в такой-то". Например, для замыканий генерируется класс, создается объект этого класса и переменная становится его полем. using разворачивается в try-finally и так далее. Я решил попробовать посмотреть это, поставил IlSpy, написал вот такой код:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action print = delegate { };

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var fix = i;
            print += () => Console.Write(fix);
        }

        print();

        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"G:\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var canIReadIt = fs.CanRead;
        }
    }
```

Но у меня вместо "зазерькалья" получилось практически то же самое, даже банальный using не развернулся, не говоря уж о замыканиях:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action print = delegate
    {
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int fix = i;
        print = (Action)Delegate.Combine(print, (Action)delegate
        {
            Console.Write(fix);
        });
    }
    print();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("G:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        bool canIReadIt = fs.CanRead;
    }
}
```

В чем подвох? Я ожидал увидеть нечто такое (код взят из статьи, в которой я прочитал про "развертку"):

```
// Было
public void Run()
{
   int e = 1;
   Foo(x => x + e);
}


// Компилятор развернул в такое
public void Run()
{
   DisplayClass c = new DisplayClass();
   c.e = 1;  
   Foo(c.Action);
}
private sealed class DisplayClass
{
   public int e;
   public int Action(int x)
   {
      return x + e;
   }
}
```

Ну а касаемо using что-то вот такое должно было получиться, судя по книге Албахари:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"G:\test.txt", FileMode.Open)
try 
{
    var canIReadIt = fs.CanRead;
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: какая версия ilspy?

Comment: @Aziz Umarov ILSpy version 6.2.0.6062-preview1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятны мне ваши ожидания. Но если вам нужно увидеть сам IL то нажмите сюда [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или уберите галочки тут (View -> Options)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и посмотрите на результат. Думаю вы поймете какой он на самом деле этот код

Comment: Исправил вопрос, в конец добавил примеры того, что я ожидал увидеть

Comment: @DenisDyatlov Дополнил ответ

Comment: Здорово, заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/decompiler/).

По умолчанию декомпилирует вот в такое:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Action action = (Action) (() => {});
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; ++index)
    {
      int fix = index;
      action += (Action) (() => Console.Write(fix));
    }
    action();
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("G:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
      bool canRead = fileStream.CanRead;
    }
  }
}
```

Но после переключения одного чекбокса

[image: скриншот чекбокса]

получается полный код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Test
{
  [CompilerGenerated]
  private static Action CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2;

  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    if (Test.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2 == null)
    {
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      Test.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2 = new Action((object) null, __methodptr(\u003CMain\u003Eb__0));
    }
    Action action = Test.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2;
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; ++index)
    {
      Test.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass3 cDisplayClass3 = new Test.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass3();
      cDisplayClass3.fix = index;
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      action = (Action) Delegate.Combine((Delegate) action, (Delegate) new Action((object) cDisplayClass3, __methodptr(\u003CMain\u003Eb__1)));
    }
    action();
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("G:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
      bool canRead = fileStream.CanRead;
    }
  }

  public Test()
  {
    base.\u002Ector();
  }

  [CompilerGenerated]
  private static void \u003CMain\u003Eb__0()
  {
  }

  [CompilerGenerated]
  private sealed class \u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass3
  {
    public int fix;

    public \u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass3()
    {
      base.\u002Ector();
    }

    public void \u003CMain\u003Eb__1()
    {
      Console.Write(this.fix);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Пользовался dotPeek, плохо template декомпилирует и varargs. Остальное вроде неплохо